# How to bind WPF radio button selection to Viewmodel using convertes?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a WPF-MVVM application...

I have 3 Radio button controls - with three options => "Individual", "Group" and "Both".
All 3 have same Group name...that means only one of these radio button can be selected.

I can have three properties in viewmodel...for each of these three options...and can check which one is selected.

```
Function()
{
  if (Is_Individual_property)
  {
   // Individual selected
  }

  if (Is_Group_property)
  {
   // group selected
  }
  if (Is_Both_property)
  {
   // Both selected
  }
}
```

But I think this is **not** best approach.

Can I have just one property in viewmodel and bind the values accordingly ?

Comment: IMO change data type of your model to enum. It's more meaningful for mutual exclusive selections of your radio button, and for representing it in wpf you can render all options of your enum.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about having a single property and managing multiple values using a converter. For example:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToStringValueConverter x:Key="BooleanToStringValueConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton1"
                     GroupName="Group1"
                     Content="Value1"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value1}" />
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton2"
                     GroupName="Group1"
                     Content="Value2"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value2}" />
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton3"
                     GroupName="Group1"
                     Content="Value3"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value3}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
public class BooleanToStringValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToString(value).Equals(System.Convert.ToString(parameter)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _property1;
    public String Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set { _property1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Property1"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MyClass() { Property1 = "Value1" };
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for converters..But I have one question..Can we use a enum instead of strings in ConverterParameter